# Symfony Forms Error: Entity of type "..." passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic, dynamic-forms

## Objective

I am trying to make a basic form that signs a new player up for a sport.  This is taken from the Symfony 
example at:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

## The Code

**I have 3 entities:**

PlayerList
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Entity/PlayerList.php

Sport
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Entity/Sport.php

Position
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Entity/Position.php

**I have a form:**

NewPlayerType
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Form/NewPlayerType.php

**I have a controller**:

NewPlayerController
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Controller/NewPlayerController.php

## The Error:

```
Entity of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?
```

## Details:

I seem to get this error whenever I create a form using the form builder that is of type, "EntityType" like so:

**Reference**:
https://github.com/ChimeraBlack1/Symphart/blob/main/src/Form/NewPlayerType.php  **(line 22)**

```
    ->add('sport', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Sport::class,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->orderBy('s.sport', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'sport',
    ])
```

It seems to me that this is happening because I am referencing "Sport::class" in the "NewPlayerType" form.  If I were to reference the "PlayerList::class", I don't experience the error.  But how do I get fields based on other entities like this to populate on a single form?  I'm missing something here conceptually I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out after something like 20 hours of googling, facepalming and rage tears.

The problem was with the relationship I had setup between entities.  I had "OneToMany" relationships where I should have had "ManyToOne".

If you ever you see this issue, re-write your relationships from a "backwards" perspective, and that should do the trick.

Thanks!